# What is the meaning of the phrase "to the extent that"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase "to the extent that"? Is the phrase equivalent to "to that extent", which I suppose means "to that degree"?

Answer (score 7):

There are two related meanings to the phrase *to the extent that*. The first, relatively concrete, is to set a measurable limit on a statement. Consider

> [We are of opinion and find that the charge of 12 cents per 100 pounds was unreasonable **to the extent that** *it exceeded 10 cents per 100 pounds*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rtM6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA433&dq=%22to%20the%20extent%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6hISlvNLQAhUB6CYKHUk5DZ8Q6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22to%20the%20extent%20that%22&f=false)....

In other words, the charge was unreasonably excessive, and we know by exactly how much it was, namely by an extra 2 cents per hundredweight.
The second usage is limiting as well, but it's more abstract and comparative, equating the scope of one claim to that of another. For instance, from *[The SAGE Handbook of Organizational Behavior](https://books.google.com/books?id=q5LTTMglfJ8C&pg=PA324&dq=%22to%20the%20extent%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDzOriutLQAhXCOCYKHSHrAps4FBDoAQggMAE#v=onepage&q=%22to%20the%20extent%20that%22&f=false)*, J Barling and C Cooper editors:

> A core premise of this theory in that a goal is motivating **to the extent that** *an individual can visualize its attainment*.

This says that some goal will motivate people, but only as much as they can see in their mind's eye what happens when the goal is met. You could dispute this claim by saying that zealots are motivated by devotion and don't need to visualize results at all to stay motivated. But the SAGE theory says otherwise, linking motivation and visualization and saying that the latter limits the former.

You'll notice that what follows *that* in the phrase *to the extent that* is a clause. (I've made those *italic* in the two examples above.) The word *that* is a subordinating conjuction, i.e., a word that links the independent clause to the subordinate clause.

In the phrase *to that extent*, *that* is a determinative modifying *extent* and pointing out to us which extent is meant. We could modify the first example to say

> The charge of 12 cents per 100 pounds exceeded the limit of 10 cents per 100 pounds. To **that extent** it was unreasonable.

The word *that* now refers to the 2 cent overcharge that was originally described in the clause *it exceeded 10 cents per 100 pounds*.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning depends on the whole sentence.

Basic meaning of

> to the extent that

means

> to the limits that